# Accessing data inside a closure after it has been completed

Tags: swift, asynchronous, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, closures

I want to be able to access the results array, after all the data has been added from Firebase to my array. Every time I try this, I get nil array.

Objective is to have a list of location info objects in an array, loaded through Firebase.

My code snippet:

```
    class func loadData(){
    let root = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let locationSummary = root.child("LocSummary")

    locationSummary.observe(.childAdded,with: { (snapshot) in
        print("inside closure")
        let values = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let name = values?["Name"] as? String ?? ""
        let rating = values?["Rating"] as? Int
        let latitude = values?["Latitude"] as? Double
        let longitude = values?["Longitude"] as? Double
        let musicType = values?["Music"] as? String ?? ""

        let loc = LocationInfo.init(name: name, rating: rating!, lat: 
latitude!, long: longitude!, musicTyp: musicType)
        resultsArray.append(loc)


    })

}
```

Comment: Use a completion handler.

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: Has it helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class func loadData(completion: @escaping (_ location: LocationInfo) -> Void) {
    let root = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let locationSummary = root.child("LocSummary")

    locationSummary.observe(.childAdded,with: { (snapshot) in
        print("inside closure")
        let values = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let name = values?["Name"] as? String ?? ""
        let rating = values?["Rating"] as? Int
        let latitude = values?["Latitude"] as? Double
        let longitude = values?["Longitude"] as? Double
        let musicType = values?["Music"] as? String ?? ""

        let loc = LocationInfo.init(name: name, rating: rating!, lat: 
latitude!, long: longitude!, musicTyp: musicType)
        completion(loc)
    })
}
```

In your cycle add something like this:

```
func getArray(completion: @escaping (_ yourArray: [LocationInfo]) -> Void {
    var resultsArray = [LocationInfo]()
    let countOfLoadedItems = 0

    for item in yourArrayForCycle { // or your own cycle. Implement your logic
         loadData(completion: { location in
                         countOfLoadedItems += 1
                         resultsArray.append(location)
                         if countOfLoadedItems == yourArrayForCycle.count {
                             completion(resultsArray)
                         }
         })
    }
}
```

Then in function, where you wants your data:

```
getArray(completion: { result in 
    yourArrayToFill = result
    // reload data etc..
})
```

Something like this. Adapt it to your solution.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank You. This helps :)

Comment: @MinonWeerasinghe glad to hear:)